# Factor out a root from this polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let a be a root of $f$, ie. $ a^3 + a^2 = -1, f = x^3 + x^2 + 1 = (x-a)(x^2+..??)$

I tried this but got $f=(x-a)(x^2 + 2ax + 2a^2)$ which obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. If $a^3 + a^2 = -1$ then
$$x^3+x+1=(x-a)(x^2+Ax+B)=x^3+(A-a)x^2+(B-aA)x-aB$$
which implies that $A=a+1$ and $B=a+a^2$. However this not helpful for the factorization...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $f(x)=(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)=x^3+(b-a)x^2+(c-ab)x-ca$ which is implies that:
\begin{align}
b-a=1\\
c-ab=0\\
-ca=1
\end{align} 
The above equations can be solved for $b$ and $c$. However, solution to these equations is conditioned by $a$ (not for all $a$ you can solve these equations for $b$ and $c$). Obviously, this is related to the fact that $a$ is a root of $f(x)=0$.